# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip entries count limit exceeded: 100000

Tags: java

I'm trying to decompile a 528Mb jar, but it seems like it's too big:

```
$ du -sch build/*
528M    large.jar
528M    total

$ jadx -d decompiled large.jar
INFO  - loading ...
ERROR - Failed to process zip file: large.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to process zip file: large.jar
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.visitZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:115)
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.readZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:121)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.DexFileLoader.collectDexFromZip(DexFileLoader.java:90)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.DexFileLoader.load(DexFileLoader.java:73)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.DexFileLoader.loadDexFromFile(DexFileLoader.java:50)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.DexFileLoader.collectDexFiles(DexFileLoader.java:45)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.DexInputPlugin.loadFiles(DexInputPlugin.java:37)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.DexInputPlugin.loadFiles(DexInputPlugin.java:33)
        at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.loadInputFiles(JadxDecompiler.java:133)
        at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.load(JadxDecompiler.java:117)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.processAndSave(JadxCLI.java:48)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.execute(JadxCLI.java:36)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.main(JadxCLI.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip entries count limit exceeded: 100000, last entry: com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/UploadSigningCertificateResult.class
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.visitZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:110)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
ERROR - Failed to process zip file: large.jar
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to process zip file: large.jar
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.visitZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:115)
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.readZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:121)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaFileLoader.collectFromZip(JavaFileLoader.java:83)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaFileLoader.loadReader(JavaFileLoader.java:63)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaFileLoader.loadFromFile(JavaFileLoader.java:42)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaFileLoader.collectFiles(JavaFileLoader.java:37)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaInputPlugin.loadClassFiles(JavaInputPlugin.java:32)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaInputPlugin.loadFiles(JavaInputPlugin.java:28)
        at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.loadInputFiles(JadxDecompiler.java:133)
        at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.load(JadxDecompiler.java:117)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.processAndSave(JadxCLI.java:48)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.execute(JadxCLI.java:36)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.main(JadxCLI.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip entries count limit exceeded: 100000, last entry: com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/UploadSigningCertificateResult.class
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.visitZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:110)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
ERROR - Failed to load class data for file: large.jar:META-INF/native/osx/libjansi.jnilib
jadx.plugins.input.java.utils.JavaClassParseException: Unknown constant pool tag: 0
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.data.ConstantType.getTypeByTag(ConstantType.java:45)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.data.ClassOffsets.readConstPool(ClassOffsets.java:27)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.data.ClassOffsets.<init>(ClassOffsets.java:11)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.data.JavaClassData.<init>(JavaClassData.java:34)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaClassReader.loadClassData(JavaClassReader.java:18)
        at jadx.plugins.input.java.JavaLoadResult.visitClasses(JavaLoadResult.java:32)
        at jadx.core.dex.nodes.RootNode.loadClasses(RootNode.java:92)
        at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.load(JadxDecompiler.java:120)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.processAndSave(JadxCLI.java:48)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.execute(JadxCLI.java:36)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.main(JadxCLI.java:20)
ERROR - Process error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to process zip file: large.jar
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.visitZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:115)
        at jadx.api.ResourcesLoader.loadFile(ResourcesLoader.java:144)
        at jadx.api.ResourcesLoader.load(ResourcesLoader.java:46)
        at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.getResources(JadxDecompiler.java:399)
        at jadx.api.JadxDecompiler.load(JadxDecompiler.java:122)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.processAndSave(JadxCLI.java:48)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.execute(JadxCLI.java:36)
        at jadx.cli.JadxCLI.main(JadxCLI.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip entries count limit exceeded: 100000, last entry: com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/UploadSigningCertificateResult.class
        at jadx.api.plugins.utils.ZipSecurity.visitZipEntries(ZipSecurity.java:110)
        ... 7 common frames omitted

$
```

I've tried decompiling with [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/), but no luck

adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content
adding more filler content

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do I decompile large.jar?

Comment: Build your own version of jadx with that limit increased/removed.

Comment: setting a limit for this type of task means affecting the memory and processing resources consumed by the computer, as indicated in the issues, it is advisable to do so and try various options since it is sometimes indeterminable because this type of files may contain errors that prevent its decompilation.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [issue thread](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/issues/371) that is similar to your case, where has closed and the last comment says to set heap memory limit to 16 GB (`-Xmx16`).

I think there are not concretly enough a correct solution that solve your task, but you can try different options to optimize a large `jar` file decompilation:

- Edit `bin/jadx-gui` or `bin/jadx-gui.bat` (Windows) to change heap memory to 16 GB

`DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Xms128M" "-Xmx16g" "-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd" "-Dswing.aatext=true" "-XX:+UseG1GC"'`

- On Windows inside `jadx-gui.exe` directory create a new text file **jadx-gui.l4j.ini** and write **`-Xmx16g`**